# Cannot install .ipa file to my iPhone 4s fom itunes

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I can not install my .ipa file to my iphone 4s device somehow. 
However, I have successfully installed it to my 3g device.
I have taken care of every single distribution step. I have provided my iPhone 4s UDID and everything.

I'm using Xcode Version 4.2.

Comment: Solved it. create new distribution profile and did things from scratch and its all good now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before where it worked on my 3G but not 4s.  This occurred for iOS ipa's built with Flash CS, but it may be related to yours.

The problem was that my application identifier for deployment on Flash CS (looks like com.mycompany.appname) was misspelled from how it set was in the provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have fixed it by creating new provision profile. and for some reason its working fine on my iphone 4s.